# What's the difference between \argmin and \arg\min?

Tags: math, latex

I have this small question about using Latex.

What's the difference between `\argmin` and `\arg\min`?

Is it just a different way to express argument minimum or do they represent different meanings?

I first thought they were just different ways. Even though the subscripts sometimes are not placed at the center of them both.

Then when I'm reading a paper about Variational Inference, they seem to be different:
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

The paper is *An Introduction to Variational Inference*, from https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.13083.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `\argmin` command by default, the paper uses this command to make one:

```tex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
```

Doing `\arg\min` includes a space by default as you mentioned, if you want to avoid this you can instead do:

```
\arg\!\min
```

There shouldn't be a difference between doing these two as far as I'm aware. The latter may be useful when you can't import packages (on a stackoverflow answer for example).